# reading a huge file from a server.

Tags: python, shell, unix

So I am new in this field and am not sure how to do this!!But basically here is what i did.

I sshed to somehost.

```
ssh hostname
username: foo
password: bar
```

In one of the directories, there is a huge csv file.. abc.csv

Now, i dont want to copy that file to my local.. but read it from there.

When I asked the folks around, they said that I can write a unix script and get the data in my python program from tehre.
I am not sure what that means?
Any clues?
Also, i am using windows env.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Standard output of the remote command is passed to standard output of the `ssh` process. If you script reads the file from standard input, you can try

```
ssh user@hostname 'cat abc.csv' | python myScript.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a python script on the Linux server.

Or you could subprocess.Popen a Cygwin ssh (with passwordless, passphraseless authentication) and treat it as though the file is on your Windows system.  The cygwin ssh could just run "ssh linux.server.com cat my-file.csv" and then read the content line by line back on the windows system in python.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html